# Boost.serialization unregistered class exception with serialized class defined in a runtime-linked shared library

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, dynamic-linking, boost-serialization

I am trying to create a modular game system, and I would like user - defined classes to be able to be serialized. To to this, I am placing classes derrived from a polymorphic base class. I am running into troubles while trying to implement serialization on this class. I keep getting the unregistered class exception (a runtime error).

Here is a minimal test case:

Environment: windows 8.1 MSVC++ 12 (visual studio 2013)

parent_class.h -- defines the parent_class class that is polymorphic

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

class parent_class
{

protected:

    friend boost::serialization::access;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(x) & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(y);
    }

    float x;
    float y;

public:

    explicit parent_class(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    // virtual deconstructor to make it polymorphic
    virtual ~parent_class()
    {
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(parent_class);
```

Main.cpp - the only .cpp in the .exe

```
#include "parent_class.h"

#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>

typedef parent_class* addChildFun(float, float, float);

int main()
{
    // acquire module
    HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("SerializationDLL.dll");
    assert(module);

    // acquire function ptr
    FARPROC addChildRaw = GetProcAddress(module, "makeChild");
    assert(addChildRaw);
    addChildFun* addChildPtr = reinterpret_cast<addChildFun*>(addChildRaw);

    // make polymorphic pointer
    parent_class* child = addChildPtr(325.f, 214.f, 2.5f);

    // INIT BOOST SERIALIZIZATION ARCHIVE
    std::ofstream stream{ "file.txt" };
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive arch{ stream };

    try
    {

        arch << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(child);

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what(); // prints "unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
    }


    std::cin.get();
    delete child;
}
```

And finally here is my child_class.cpp -- the only .cpp in the .dll

```
#include <parent_class.h>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>


class child_class : public parent_class
{
    friend boost::serialization::access;

public:

    float z;

    explicit child_class(float x, float y, float z)
        : parent_class(x, y),
        z(z)
    {
    }

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("owner", boost::serialization::base_object<parent_class>(*this));

        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z);
    }

    virtual ~child_class() override
    {

    }

};

// export the class
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(child_class)

// yes I am using MSVC -- hence dllexport
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) parent_class* makeChild(float x, float y, float z)
{
    return new child_class(x, y, z);
}
```

All of the code should be pretty self-explanatory -- If you have any questions, feel free to comment.

Sorry that it's a lot of code -- I couldn't really cut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after a painstaking amount of effort, I found the solution, and it resided in two lines of code.

The problem seemed to be that the map that stored the associations between the GUID for a class and the implementation was defined twice, because it resided in a .lib file that both the .dll and the .exe were linked to. The obvious solution to this is using the dynamic linking support for the Boost.serialization library.

How to use this is to put a `#define BOOST_SERIALIZATION_DYN_LINK 1` at the beginning of every .cpp file that used the serialization library. This way, the code is only instantiated once, and boost can find the class in the map.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem seemed to be that the map that stored the associations between the GUID for a class and the implementation was defined twice, because it resided in a .lib file that both the .dll and the .exe were linked to. The obvious solution to this is using the dynamic linking support for the Boost.serialization library."

This problem is really an issue with the way that static linking works. Your solution of forcing the DLL version will work, but it's not the best.
The problem can better be addressed by not using inline serialization function.  So replace

```
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("owner", boost::serialization::base_object<parent_class>(*this));
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z);
}
```

with

```
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version);
```

and include in your child *.cpp file

```
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("owner", boost::serialization::base_object<parent_class>(*this));

    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z);
}
template child_class::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>;
template child_class::serialize<boost::archive::text_iarchive>;
```

In other words - avoid usage of inline functions.  This will guarantee that you'll get one and only one instantiation of the serialization functions.  This will work for both static and shared library builds. It will also eliminate confusion which can sometimes arise from violation of the "one definition rule"

BTW don't add things like e#define BOOST_SERIALIZATION_DYN_LINK 1 in your source files, but rather in the compiler command line via the make or project file.  This way you preserve the ability to use your code as a static lib, shared lib or directly imported into your project.

Comment: Does this work with classes that aren't defined at compile time, but at runtime, in the case of a dynamically linked DLL or SO file? In short, the exe can't know about the class in the DLL, because I am trying to write a truly modular system.

Comment: I tried to implement this -- and cannot seem to. I am unsure what your solution entails. Is the problem that the serialize function in child_class is being instantiated twice, because that rests in a .cpp file that is not included anywhere, or is it the problem that parent_class is being instantiated twice?